# Request photolibrary permission on ios causing watchos to crash?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, ios10, watchos-3

OS: IOS 10 and watchos3

I noticed an issue when developing my latest app.

My app needs to request for photolibrary permission to save some images.
In both watch app and ios, I have **added the photo library access permission** in the plist.

I noticed that when I press request permission on my ios device when the watch app is running on foreground.

**Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**

Once the ios permission request is successful, the **watch app will crash**, with the following code **Program ended with exit code: 0**, which seems like os level behavior to me.

```html
    
    func requestPhotoLibraryPermission(){
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                
                break
            default:
                self.showErrorMessage(title: NSLocalizedString("Permission Denied", comment: "Permission Denied"), message:  NSLocalizedString("You can enable Photo Library permission from the settings app", comment: "You can enable Photo Library permission from the settings app") ,completionBlock: {
                })
                // place for .NotDetermined - in this callback status is already determined so should never get here
                break
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

As you can see, the code is very straight forward. Anyone experience similar issue? Is there any known workaround?

Comment: Same issue with Microphone permission.

Comment: Same issue with Apple Music

Answer (score 2):

Tested with a brand new project, same issue , I believe iOS inform watchos to restart the app when permission changes.

Same behavior when you change your app permissions at iOS setting page and go back to your app.

Answer (score -1):

Forgive me if I misunderstood, but did you add the key: "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" and usage description for the key value to your plist?